# Specific date format and optional time included with moment.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

Team,
I have got a Typescript method like below.

```
public getDateDisplayFormat(dateFormat: string, displayTime: boolean): string {

}
```

The "dateFormat" parameter can be of any with/without date format like `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YY HH:mmss Z` or `MM/DD/YY HH:mmss Z` or any other valid formats.

But based on the displayTime parameter I need to add/remove time value in the date.

I tried L and LLT formats but those are giving just `MM/DD/YYYY` irrespective of my date format.

The dateFormat is dynamic based on the client and so I cannot change it from `DD/MM` into `MM/DD`.

So, my dateFormat which is passed should remain same but only the time portion should add/remove in the format.

Please suggest how I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public getDateDisplayFormat(dateFormat: string, displayTime: boolean): string {
    let format = dateFormat.substr(0,str.indexOf(' ')); //get the format by splitting the string on first space. Date goes at index 0, rest goes at index 1.
    if(displayTime){
//if format length is greater than 1, it means that dateFormat had both date and time format so return it, else, append time format and return it.
    dateTime = format.length > 1 ? dateFormat : format[0] + "your time format";
    return dateTime;
    }
// if time format is not needed just return the date format.
    return format[0];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan for you quick response.
But, I want to return the format and not the value.
For Ex:
if my inputs are like "DD/MM/YY", true then I should return "DD/MM/YY h:mm A". Because the second parameter is to add the time format.
And, if it is false and the time format exists in the dateFormat then the time format text alone should be removed from the dateFormat parameter and return it.

Comment: So basically you want a function that either appends a time format or removes a time format from an already appended string based on your second parameter?

Comment: I have edited the answer. See if it is what you need.

Comment: Yes, this really gives me the path what I should do. Great. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great... kindly upvote and accept the answer to help others too.